# Shape modified by AffineTransform is rendering reverse from expectations

Tags: java, matrix, transformation, coordinate-systems, affinetransform

I have a few geometric shapes which are in different co-ordinates that I want to be brought to the center of the panel.  I have written a function called "Set Scale," which is bringing it in to center, but the shape is reversed.

My Code:

```
private void SetScale1(Graphics2D gr, int gr_width , int gr_height, double left_x , double right_x , double top_y , double bottom_y ){


    Rectangle2D drawing_rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(left_x, top_y, right_x - left_x, bottom_y - top_y);
 double drawing_cx=( left_x+ right_x) / 2;
 double drawing_cy =(top_y + bottom_y) / 2;

AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(-1 * drawing_cx, -1 * drawing_cy);
//gr.translate(-1 * drawing_cx, -1 * drawing_cy);
//gr.TranslateTransform(0, 0)
double scale_x=gr_width / drawing_rect.getWidth();
double scale_y=gr_height / Math.abs(drawing_rect.getHeight());

scale_x = Math.min(scale_x, scale_y);
scale_y = scale_x;
scale_x = Math.abs(scale_x);
// at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale_x, -1 * scale_y);
//gr.transform(tt);
gr.transform(at);

//' Translate to center over the drawing area.
double graphics_cx =gr_width / 2;
double graphics_cy = gr_height / 2;
gr.translate(graphics_cx, graphics_cy);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Tried this... it Works:-)

Thanks for the help:-)

Rectangle2D drawing_rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(left_x, top_y, right_x - left_x, bottom_y - top_y);
      drawing_cx=(left_x+ right_x) / 2;
      drawing_cy =(top_y + bottom_y) / 2;

```
 at= AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance( -1* drawing_cx,  -1*drawing_cy);
//gr.translate(-1 * drawing_cx, -1 * drawing_cy);
//gr.TranslateTransform(0, 0)
double scale_x=gr_width / drawing_rect.getWidth();
double scale_y=gr_height / Math.abs(drawing_rect.getHeight());

scale_x = Math.min(scale_x, scale_y);
scale_y = scale_x;
scale_x = Math.abs(scale_x);
// at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale_x, -1 * scale_y);

gr.scale(Math.round(scale_x), Math.round( scale_y));
//gr.scale(1.2, 1.2);
//gr.transform(tt);
gr.transform(at);

//' Translate to center over the drawing area.
 graphics_cx =gr_width / 2;
 graphics_cy = gr_height / 2;
gr.translate(graphics_cx, graphics_cy);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the description given, I would recommend you take a look at your transformation matrix:

```
AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(-1 * drawing_cx, -1 * drawing_cy);
```

Are you certain that your tx and ty parameters are correct?  Here is the matrix returned by [getTranslationInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getTranslateInstance%28double,%20double%29):

```
[   1    0    tx  ]
[   0    1    ty  ]
[   0    0    1   ]
```

The -1 values you have set in the parameters for `getTranslationInstance` seem suspect to me... unless I've missed something, I don't see any reason why they should be negative.  Negative values should [mirror the result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Scaling), so that may very well be why you're seeing the reversal. Try changing those (they will change the tx and ty fields in the matrix above, respectively) and let us know if it helps.